# Store JSON iTunes Search API data

Tags: objective-c, ios, itunes

How can I use the iTunes search API from within iOS/Obj-c ?

I know of this link of course..

http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html

I just don't understand how you use obj-c/iOS with it.

I want to be able to read the JSON results, whether they be broad or just 1 result and store the apps name (or would that be ID?), any images, rating etc in my server database (using parse.com).

How can I do that, and is that allowed by the Apple developer terms?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like you just make the requests and parse the results.  No auth or anything else fancy...

```
NSString *urlString = @"https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=jack+johnson";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                           if (!error) {
                               NSError* parseError;
                               id parse = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&parseError];
                               NSLog(@"%@", parse);
                           }
                       }];
```

The JSON parser will yield arrays of dictionaries for collection calls and (probably) dictionaries for single objects.

Comment: Ha, that looks too simple but I just tried it and it works :), how would I restrict it to just games? and to your knowledge (I've googled this and it's hard to find info on it) is storing data from this JSON data ok with Apple? I presume it is because it seems that's what all the analytics services do.

Comment: Hmm I've just realised maybe that's what I need, I need to search the app store, not iTunes, although I'm not sure if in this context they are one and the same or different, either way there doesn't seem to be an app search term. I'll mark this question as answered and post another question specific to the app store, thanks.